# In ASP.NET, What could cause image manipulation to fail when using Fx or chrome, but succeed when using IE?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, file-upload, cross-browser

I am in a rather unusual pickle. I am modifying an image uploader and I thought I had it working. It needed to:

1. take a file from the client and upload it to server.

   If file is an image, perform resizing operations on it.

   If file is an image, create a thumbnail.

What I have works great when uploading images with Internet Explorer 8. But, when I upload images using Chrome, or Firefox3.+, the image gets uploaded but steps 2 and 3 are not performed. I don't get any server errors or anything. As 2 and 3 are steps that are performed on the server I have no idea how a change in browser could effect them.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my checking for whether the file is an image or not. But, for the sake of being thorough, here's the code I use:

```
try
{
    string Filename = FileSystemUtilities.CleanupFilename(Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
    Filename = hpf.FileName;
    string FileToSave = DestDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileName(Filename);
    hpf.SaveAs(FileToSave);
    bool IsImageFileType = ImageUtilities.IsImage(Filename, imageExtensions);

    // below does not seem to execute when using non ie browser
    // everything is smooth sailing when using ie.
    if (IsImageFileType)
    {
        ImageUtilities.ResizeImageIfNecessary(FileToSave, mainMaxWidth, mainMaxHeight);
        ImageUtilities.CreateThumbnail(FileToSave, thumbMaxWidth, thumbMaxHeight);
    }

    ValidOperation++;
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} uploaded successfully<br/>", Filename);
}
```

Any thoughts? Why would server side code behave differently based on browser?

### Edit: ImageUtilities.IsImage()

```
    public static bool IsImage(string file, string[] imageExtensions)
    {
        file = Path.GetFullPath(file);

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            string CurrentFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file);
            return imageExtensions.Count(x => x == CurrentFileExtension) > 0 ? true : false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false; //file doesn't exist
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should call `Path.Combine`.

Comment: What is `Filename = hpf.FileName` for?

Comment: Not 100% certain. I'm editing pre-existing code that's a little messy.

Comment: Thanks for the Path.Combine tip.

Comment: What's `ImageUtilities.IsImage`?

Comment: @SLaks - editing question to show IsImage()

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you aren't using IE8.

Comment: Why is that? I am using IE8... and chrome... and Firefox to test. The images are handled correctly when using IE, and they are not when using chrome or Fx

Comment: I guessed a different implementation of `ShowImage`.  Anyway, why are you checking whether the file exists?

Comment: Because i want to be sure that the file exists before I look for an extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This difference would be caused by a difference in the filename sent by the browsers.
For example, some browsers include the full path.

Your `ImageUtilities.IsImage` function can't handle the filename sent by non-IE browsers.

**EDIT**: Your function is very wrong.
Change it to

```
return imageExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file), 
                                StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Hmm... I did not know that. How would I check for the path?

Comment: Just call `Path.GetFileName`, which will strip it if it's there.  You should rewrite the code from scratch; it's very poor code.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. But you're tone is rather offensive. I am here because I want to improve my code. So, you telling me that my code is poor and needs to be re-written from scratch without giving me a reason is rather inflamatory.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound offensive. You said that this isn't your code, and that you've gotten it from somewhere else.

Comment: I believe your code would return true even for "IAmNotAjpg.doc" unless I missunderstand what `.contains` does.

Comment: You're misunderstanding it.  I'm checking whether the set of extensions contains your extension, not whether your string contains an extension.

Comment: @SLaks - Yeah... Most of the code is from somewhere else, that specific function was mine though - lol :-)

Comment: The `IsImage` function appears to be confused about what kind of path it takes.  Since all it does is check the extension, it shouldn't care about the full path or the existence of the file.

Comment: Ah... I see... cool. I love fewer lines to accomplish the same thing... and as a bonus, your code solves some problems that mine had. I'm going to go test this out.

Comment: Note that `GetExtension` includes a leading `.`.

Comment: Yes sir... so does the `string[]` of imageExtensions ie: `imageExtensions[0] = ".jpg"`